# is there any text preprocessing which can detect san andreas as a single word Api for python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am working twitter data for analysis but before analysis, i want to preprocess data. i tried nltk.word_tokenize(), but they don't remove punctuation and they don't understand san andreas and a single word but in tweets, there are many words like this. here is code

`def inital():
    return 0
def get_vocab(lst):
    vocab_count=defaultdict(inital)
    i=0
    for txt in lst:
        if type(txt)!=float:
            txt=txt.decode("utf8")
            for words in nltk.word_tokenize(txt):
                vocab_count[words]+=1
    return vocab_count`

Comment: Please show the code you have got so far...

Comment: def inital():
    return 0
def get_vocab(lst):
    vocab_count=defaultdict(inital)
    i=0
    for txt in lst:
        if type(txt)!=float:
            txt=txt.decode("utf8")
            for words in nltk.word_tokenize(txt):
                vocab_count[words]+=1
    return vocab_count

Comment: See here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17294/nlp-what-are-some-popular-packages-for-multi-word-tokenization

Comment: @jayelm   your link is helpful but i need it staford corenlp in python can you tell me how to use corenlp in python